# How to fix "Expected expression before "=" token"?

Tags: c++

Turns out to have the error

> expected expression before '=' token

```
#include <iostream>
#define e = 2.71828

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, b, c;

  cout << "put n: ";
  cin >> n;
  b = e - (1 / (e * e));
  for (int a = 0; a <= n; a++) {
    if (a == 0) {
      b = c;
      c = 1 - a * c;
    }
  }
  cout << "积分值为：" << c << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give the full error mesagge. On which line occurs the error?

Comment: `#define e 2.71828` ... you dont need the `=`

Comment: You need to take a step back and reread about the preprocessor. Preprocessor macros doesn't work like other statements in C++.

Comment: Remove '=' after `e` in `define`. change `#define e = 2.71828` to `#define e 2.71828`

Comment: Also your for loop is useless, because it only changes something when a equals 0. The other times, it does nothing

Comment: As a solution, I would rather recommend you *don't* use a macro, but instead use C++ constants, like e.g. `constexpr e = 2.71828;`

Comment: And please use more decimal places for `e`; at least as adequate for a `double`. (I have the luxury of relying on Boost for my constants).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `=` with `define`

Simply change `#define e = 2.71828` into `#define e (2.71828)`

---

Take a look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) page if you want to refresh your memory on how the `#define` pre-processor directives work.

Comment: Your link is broken!

Answer (score 2):

A macro defines a text substitution;

```
#define a b
```

makes the preprocessor replace `a` with `b`.
Note that there is no `=`.

You are defining `e` to mean `= 2.71828`.

Expand it and you get:

```
b = = 2.71828 - (1 / (= 2.71828 * = 2.71828))
```

Removing the `=` is the obvious fix, but you really should leave the 1970s behind and use

```
constexpr double e = 2.71828;
```

Comment: And leave the 19th century behind and use more precision for `e`: 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995 is a good start and good for quadruple precision.

Comment: @Bathsheba For all I know, the value OP is using is the value OP is intending to use.

Answer (score 0):

`#define e 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995`

is the fix, else the preprocessor will expand `=` into the constant and yield somewhat cryptic compiler diagnostics.

Note that I've also used more decimal places for Euler's number: your constant is a poor choice for a `double` (and even a single precision `float`). The value I present will be truncated at compile-time and is good enough for quadruple precision. It's a pity that the C++ standard library doesn't define the constant for you (and include *pi* too).

Another more modern formulation is

```
constexpr double e = 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define e 2.71828
```

just remove "=" sign.